# čьrnъ > czarny, čьrvenъ > czervony (Polish)

Tags: historical-linguistics, sound-change, slavic-languages, polish

According to Wiktionary, Polish *czarny* is from PSl *čьrnъ, and *czervony* is from *čьrvenъ.  At least *prima facie* the soft yers appears to have become different vowels in Polish.

I'm aware of the following sound rules ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Polish_language)):

- PSl *ě* becomes *a* before unpalatized alveolars; *e* becomes *o*.
- Strong yers in PSl become *e*

The rules kind of explain *czarny* and *czervony*, but not quite.  At least according to the rule, a soft yer does not become *ě*, and *rv* in *čьrvenъ is not quite palatized (are they)?

How can the modern *czarny* and *czervony* be explained?

Comment: The tables showing the [descendants of _*čьrnъ_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/čьrnъ#Descendants) and the [descendants of _*čьvenъ_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/čьrvenъ#Descendants) show that this isn’t just a Polish oddity – the reflexes of the first yer is treated differently almost everywhere in Slavic. Since the sequence of phonemes was the same, I assume the difference in treatment must be down to stress/accent. ‘Black’ is reconstructed as _*čь̀rnъ_ which I **think** is meant to indicate a neoacute accent.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Interesting point.  A single grave accent over a yer in Wiktionary is indeed neoacute:  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:About_Proto-Slavic#Accents